# Create xml file using jsp

Tags: xml, html, jsp

Can we create a new xml file using the jsp coding anyone help me to do this?

I want to create a xml file like this

for eg:

```
<Question><para>Create a question </para><para>what is coordinate grid</para><para>pair of grids.</para><para>pair of points</para></Question>
```

using the jsp coding. If it is possible please give me the coding for that.

Comment: i tried to create a xml file using jsp coding thats all...

Comment: Let us see the code you have and what errors it gives

Comment: no i am just a learner to jsp and so i ask for the coding.

Comment: SSO is not a site to just do your work - it is to help solve an explicit issue - see http://stackoverflow.com/questions/how-to-ask if you are "just learning" search for a tutorial or book that gives example explained code

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use [Xstream](http://xstream.codehaus.org/) to serialize your object to xml. You can check [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4602210/xmlencoder-in-java-for-serialization) i think it will be helpful. Let me know if you have issues implementing it.