# how to save a Java Hashmap as a attribute in a sql table and load it back

Tags: java, mysql, jdbc, hashmap, histogram

I create a `Hashmap` for some 400 or so `objects`. I have to store the `objects` as well as the `hash maps` in the `mysql table`.

So each record of this table will have a object as well as its corresponding `hashmap`.

How do I go about achieving this as well as retrieving my `hashmap` back from the `sql table`.

The `hashmap` contains a histogram and the object that I wish to store is a image.

Comment: I don't have a direction, I don't even have keywords to Google for.

Comment: I am not even sure something like this would be possible, but it would make what I am doing very easy, if this becomes possible ! if it is not possible I have to serialize the hashmaps and reload them.

Answer (score 2):

Don't store the HashMap in the database. Store the objects which are in the HashMap in the database. I guess you can recreate your HashMap when you have all of its "values" in the database.

Answer (score 0):

I would suggest you to XML serialize your `HashMap` : https://stackoverflow.com/a/4602230/1788704

Then, put it in your `MySQL` table in a `TEXT` column.

It is certainly not the best way, but it works and you can see easily if what inside your database is correct or not.

But the problem is that storing your Hashmap in database is certainly not a good solution.

Answer (score 0):

A Map is and data container that can be compared to table in database. It stores some data. What you should is to create a table where you have an unique key to identify  and the columns that represent the content of entity.

If you have such structure then you can create an object that will represent the entity. Then you populate the data from DB to your object and store them in Map using the key.

For Example

your table

```
| ID  | NAME  | LASTNAME |
```

Your class

```
class Person {
  long id; 
  String name;
  String lastname; 

 public long getId() {
    return id;
 }
}
```

You map

Map storage = new HashMap()<>;

Potential usage

```
public Map<Long,Person> loadPersonWithName(String regexp) {

       Collection<Person> persons = searchForPersonWithName(regexp);

       if(persons.isEmpty()) {
          return Collections.emptyMap();
       }

       Map<Long,Person> result= new HashMap()<>;

       for(Person person: persons) {
           result.put(person.getId(),person);
       }

       return result;
}
```

In the method `searchForPersonWithName` you will need to implement the logic to access database and transform the query result into object of Person class.