# How to use XMLEncoder and XMLDecoder with String?

Tags: java, javabeans

Sorry this is a very new to Java question!

How does one input a String to XMLEncoder and one output a String from XMLDecoder?

The String contains information about a JavaBeans object.

Comment: try this: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4602210/xmlencoder-in-java-for-serialization

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Here is a more direct example using ByteArrayInput/OutputStream than the other question:

for class

```
static public class MyClass implements Serializable {

    private String prop;

    /**
     * Get the value of prop
     *
     * @return the value of prop
     */
    public String getProp() {
        return prop;
    }

    /**
     * Set the value of prop
     *
     * @param prop new value of prop
     */
    public void setProp(String prop) {
        this.prop = prop;
    }

}
```

read or write with:

```
static String toString(MyClass obj) {
    ByteArrayOutputStream baos = new ByteArrayOutputStream();
    XMLEncoder e = new XMLEncoder(baos);
    e.writeObject(obj);
    e.close();
    return new String(baos.toByteArray());
}

static MyClass fromString(String str) {
    XMLDecoder d = new XMLDecoder(new ByteArrayInputStream(str.getBytes()));
    MyClass obj = (MyClass) d.readObject();
    d.close();
    return obj;
}
public static void main(String[] args) {

    MyClass obj = new MyClass();
    obj.setProp("propval");
    String s = toString(obj);
    System.out.println("s = " + s);
    MyClass obj2 = fromString(s);
    System.out.println("obj2.getProp() = " + obj2.getProp());
}
```