# Java convert String to JLabel

Tags: java, string, swing, jlabel

A JLabel in java can be turned into a String (using `.toString()`)

Similarly i want to take that string which i have read from a file and turn it back into a JLabel again.

(if this is not possible would their be another way to store a JLabel in a file and then recreate it exactly again)

Comment: You could have a look at [JAXB](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/jaxb/intro/), but `JLabel` supports [`XMLEncoder`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/beans/XMLEncoder.html)

Comment: Thank you! Both seem like they would suit my purpose, which do you suggest i use?

Comment: I'd lean towards `XMLEncoder` to start with

Comment: Just create a `JLabel` in the app. and call `label.setString(string)`! Either that or **construct** the label using the `String` as argument, like `new JLabel(string)`

Comment: @AndrewThompson - i could do this, but i would also like to load the color, border, position, size, and other properties of the JLabel.

Comment: Why are you storing that group of details? Are those values adjustable by the end user? If so, why? What is this app. that allows the user to change those details?

Comment: @AndrewThompson - I am creating a game board with the JLabels as the spaces. The board is created as a JLabel matrix (2d array) and properties need to be edited. However, if you have any suggestions for a better construction i would be interested.

Comment: *"(2d array)"* So they can be arranged in a `GridLayout`? In any case, it is likely better to create a `GameModel` custom class that is a Java Bean and can be easily serialized and restored.

Comment: I have not heard of a GameModel before, can you provide a link to an example? (Thank you for your comments!)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I agree with MadProgrammer that XMLEncoder and XMLDecoder are the way to go.

[This answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33970909/how-to-use-xmlencoder-and-xmldecoder-with-string) gives you a good idea of how to use both of them, but I changed this code to specifically use JLabel.

```
String toString(JLabel jl) {
  ByteArrayOutputStream baos = new ByteArrayOutputStream();
  XMLEncoder e = new XMLEncoder(baos);
  e.writeObject(jl);
  e.close();
  return new String(baos.toByteArray());
}

JLabel fromString(String str) {
    XMLDecoder d = new XMLDecoder(new ByteArrayInputStream(str.getBytes()));
    JLabel label = (JLabel) d.readObject();
    d.close();
    return label;
}
```